# XStream dynamically convert list

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm trying to implement a generic XStream reader to read my xml. My XML have all the same tagname, but with differents ID.
Example:

XML from URL 1 returns:

```
<rss>
    <reg id="someClass">
        <ds>bla bla</ds>
    </reg>
</rss>
```

XML from URL2 returns:

```
<rss>
    <reg id="differentClass">
        <id> 1 </id>
        <location> etc </location>
    </reg>
    <reg id="differentClass">
        <id> 2 </id>
        <location> etc2 </location>
    </reg>
</rss>
```

So as you can see, they're all the same until my reg tag starts, it can be a list or a single value. But that's so far ok.
However if I implement my RSS class with my reg object referencing my "someClass" class,it works just fine, it converts and gives me the values I expect, however I need to make it generic, instead of creating N classes for same struct, I was trying to implement my RSS class this way:

```
public class RSS {
    private List<?> reg;
    public List<?> getReg() {
        return reg;
    }
    public void setReg(List<?> reg) {
        this.reg = reg;
    }
}
```

my SomeClass class:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String ds;
    //getters and setters
}
```

my differentClass:

```
public class DifferentClass{
    private String id, location;
    //getters and setters
}
```

and trying to read my XML as follows for the first url:

```
response = client.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
    xstream.ignoreUnknownElements();
    xstream.alias("rss", RSS.class);
    xstream.alias("reg", SomeClass.class);
    RSS rss = (RSS) xstream.fromXML(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    Object user = rss.getReg();
    return (SomeClass) user;
```

and for the second url, instead of 'SomeClass', use 'differentClass'. But this approach is not working, since I get the following exception:

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : ds
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /rss/reg/ds
line number         : 12
class[1]            : br.com.test.RSS
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085)
    at br.com.test.Test.get(Test.java:64)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: ds
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:91)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:85)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:80)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 78 more
```

I'm stuck in here, is it possible to implement this approach using XStream? If yes, how? I can make it work without this lib (reading tag by tag), however it would be easier for future use this lib.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that xstream tries to convert your ds as ArrayList.
Tell xstream that it is a String:

```
xstream.aliasType("ds", String.class);
```